# Upgrade cURL to latest on CentOS 5.8

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

I need to update cURL on my MediaTemple DV server with CentOS. My server is running cURL version: 7.15.5 and CentOS version: 5.8 (final).

I've seen commands like `yum update curl`, but just want to be certain before I start running commands on my server.

I saw this question "
[Upgrade cURL to latest on CentOS](https://serverfault.com/questions/321321/upgrade-curl-to-latest-on-centos) ", but I see a lot of references to Linux.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Running `yum update <package>` is generally speaking safe. Since the most recent Erratum for cURL is [RHSA-2013-0983](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2013-0983.html) from **2013** I don't expect that `yum upgrade curl` will actually do anything at all in 2016...

Running `yum update <package>` also typically [won't change the version](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting) of that package either...

You probably should also run `yum upate` without any other options regularly to install the [few security updates/bug fixes](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/rhel-server-errata.html) that still get released for RHEL/CentOS 5.

---

**EDIT** I had missed that you're still on 5.8 which is an CentOS release from **2012** that hasn't been patched since. Read [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/535606/is-there-a-big-difference-between-centos-6-4-to-6-2-and-should-i-up-down-grade/535615#535615) why that is a Bad Idea™.
If your yum configuration is correct a `yum update curl` might require installation of a number of updated dependancies as well, which are long overdue.

Comment: Josiah, you might want to read [this answer](http://serverfault.com/questions/535606/is-there-a-big-difference-between-centos-6-4-to-6-2-and-should-i-up-down-grade/535615#535615) to get more understanding about RH/CentOS's patching policy, and why HBruijn says that curl's version won't change (he's right).  It also sheds some light on why you shouldn't be running C5.8 for **anything** (5.11 is the current version of C5).

Comment: Is there a special process of upgrading CentOS? Or does the host need to do that?

Comment: In essence `yum update` and `reboot` if yum is configured correctly

Comment: @JosiahLenz On a DV server, you're responsible for keeping it up to date and secured.