# Upgrading curl on centos 6: libcurl-7.50 requires libnghttp2

Tags: centos, centos6, yum, curl

I am trying to upgrade curl but keep on getting this error:

> Package: libcurl-7.50.0-1.1.cf.rhel6.x86_64 (CityFan)
>              Requires: libnghttp2.so.14()(64bit)

I am not sure how to get this required package? I'm using `city-fan.org-release-1-13.rhel6.noarch` repo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the third party city-fan repository. This repo has dependencies which are in the EPEL repository, one of which is libnghttp2, so you must have EPEL enabled to use city-fan.

Comment: This site has instructions on how to enable EPEL: https://www.webmaster.net/tutorials/centos/how-install-epel-repo-centos.html on CentOS 6 and 7.

Comment: @Martijn What's wrong with `yum install epel-release`? Why does he make it so needlessly complicated?

Comment: `yum --enablerepo=epel install libnghttp2 -y && yum install libcurl -y && service httpd restart` this will download last curl verions from `city-fan`

Comment: This is for AWS EC2 RHEL: [link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-enable-epel/)

Answer (score 5):

Here is the complete set of commands I executed because it was not clear from the answer of Michael Hampton. Also the link to EPEL install instruction as pointed out were long and unecessary.

> yum install epel-release -y
> rpm -Uvh http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/rhel6/x86_64/city-fan.org-release-1-13.rhel6.noarch.rpm
> yum  update curl

**Updated URL 2020-08-19:** http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/rhel6/x86_64/city-fan.org-release-2-1.rhel6.noarch.rpm

Comment: The link was broken

Comment: http://www.city-fan.org/ftp/contrib/yum-repo/rhel6/x86_64/city-fan.org-release-2-1.rhel6.noarch.rpm